# android config.ini missing warning

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

when i first start open my android project it's give me this 
Warning: Missing file '/Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/.android/avd/hello.avd/config.ini'.

after updating my SDK my eclipse error list are bellow :

```
[2015-08-27 00:51:32 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:

Warning: Missing file '/Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/.android/avd/hello.avd/config.ini'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2015-08-27 00:51:38 - android-support-v7-appcompat] /Users/ferrakkembhuiyan/ferrakkem/Programming/android/UPLOAD/android/android - Eclipse/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
```

any kindly let me know how to solve this problem .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your android studio up to date?

Comment: Try deleting any run configurations you have for your app, then create a new one and run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual device / emulator hello.avd is missing a file.  You may be able to resolve this by deleting the hello.avd emulator, and creating a new emulator.

1. Go to Tools drop down menu at the top -> Android -> AVD Manager.
2. Right click hello.avd and choose "Delete"
3. Click the button in the middle "Create a new virtual device" and create a new emulator.

FYI you can also use Genymotion software emulator instead of the built-in Android Studio emulators, if the built-in emulators aren't working out for you.

Comment: thanks first solved . but other error still now showing :(

Comment: Looks like you are using styles or themes that are specific to Eclipse, and/or live in a different location in Android Studio.  I'm not sure if the these are specified in AndroidManifest and/or styles.xml, but those might be the first places to check and try changing them.